# Can limit be taken inside the measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }m(E_n) = 0$ is given, then can we take the limit inside the function? For example, in this case can I conclude $m(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } E_n) = 0$?

Comment: If $E_n$ is increasing, yes. If $E_n$ is decreasing and for some $N$ $\mu(E_N) < \infty$, yes.

Comment: Nobody ensures that $\lim_n E_n$ exists in general. So, I suppose that in general the answer is no.