# Moving limit inside the probability

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory

Reading different answers in this forum I found out some hint, but still I'm not sure of the answer.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}P\left(\bigcup_{k\ge n}^{\infty}A_k\right) = P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigcup_{k\ge n}^{\infty}A_k\right)$$
For what I understood the following is feasible because $\bigcup_{k\ge n}^{\infty}A_k$ is a decreasing sequence, is it right?

Does it hold in a generic case that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}P(A_k) = P(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}A_k)$?

In particular I'm referring to the following answers: [Can limit be taken inside the measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749374/can-limit-be-taken-inside-the-measure)

Comment: What would $\lim_k A_k$ mean?

Comment: $\mathbb P(\bigcup _{k\geq n} A_k), n\in\mathbb N$ is a decreasing sequence of probabilities. What would it even mean to take the the limit of $\bigcup _{k\geq n} A_k$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @AlvinLepik take the limsup. But I didn't get your point. could you instead answer to my question in the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can already find a good discussion of this topic [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137654/probability-of-the-limit-of-a-sequence-of-events) and in many textbooks, blogs, etc.

An explicit example of events $A_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P(A_n)\not=\mathbb P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n)$ is as follows. Let $\mathbb P$ be uniform measure on $[0,1]$. Let $B_{i,j}$ denote the interval $[\frac{i}{j},\frac{i+1}{j}]$ and let $(A_n)$ be the sequence
$$
\begin{matrix}
B_{0,1},\\
B_{0,2},&B_{1,2}\\
B_{0,3},&B_{1,3},&B_{2,3}\\
\end{matrix}
$$
and so on, reading left to right then top to bottom. Then $\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=[0,1]$, whereas the probability of the sets steadily decreases to $0$: in row $k$, all sets have proability $1/k$.

Comment: Thank you! just a curiosity, how could be formally written the sequence $A_n$ in your answer?

Comment: Given $n\geq 1$, let $k_n$ be the unique integer satisfying $\binom{k_n}{2}<n\leq \binom{k_n+1}{2}$ and let $\ell_n=n-\binom{k_n}{2}-1$. Then $A_n=B_{\ell_n,k_n}$.