# An inequality involving $\limsup$ to prove continuity of probability

Tags: probability, measure-theory, inequality, continuity, limsup-and-liminf

I am trying to understand a step in a proof about continuity of probability.

Consider $\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ a sequence of events and $A$ an event such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n = A$, where we say a sequence of events converge to a certain $A$ event iff

$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k= \limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n
$$

The proof uses the following inequality:

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_n)\leq \mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n)
$$

And the proof goes:

Notice that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $A_n\subseteq\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}{A_k}$. Then $\mathbb{P}(A_n)\leq\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k)$. Then,

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(A_n\right)\leq
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\right)
$$

The proof continues and I get it. However, my question is: how do we get the last equality between $\limsup$ and $\lim$ and the last equality between each $\lim$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the second to last equality first**

By definition of $\limsup$ for the real numbers
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sup_{m \geq n} x_m\right)
$$
It should be clear that $\forall m, n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
\bigcup_{k = m}^{\infty} A_k \subseteq \bigcup_{k = n}^{\infty} A_k \implies P\left(\bigcup_{k = m}^{\infty} A_k\right) \leq P\left(\bigcup_{k = n}^{\infty} A_k\right)
$$
when $m \geq n$. Thus it follows
$$
\sup_{m \geq n} P\left(\bigcup_{k = m}^{\infty} A_k\right) = P\left(\bigcup_{k = n}^{\infty} A_k\right)
$$
and
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} P\left(\bigcup_{k = n}^{\infty} A_k\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\sup_{m \geq n} P\left(\bigcup_{k = m}^{\infty} A_k\right)\right] = \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(\bigcup_{k = n}^{\infty} A_k\right)
$$

**For the last equality**

You cannot generally interchange the limit and probability. However, since you have a nested monotonic sequence within the probability, you can. Explicitly, each $n + 1^{\text{th}}$ term is a subset of the $n^{\text{th}}$ term:
$$
\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \supseteq \bigcup_{k=2}^{\infty} A_k \supseteq \bigcup_{k=3}^{\infty} A_k \supseteq \dots \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \supseteq \bigcup_{k = n+1}^{\infty} A_k \supseteq \dots
$$

You can find the discussion on why you can interchange the limit and probability [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3364401/moving-limit-inside-the-probability) or [here](https://yutsumura.com/interchangeability-of-limits-and-probability-of-increasing-or-decreasing-sequence-of-events/) (in many textbooks, blogs, etc.)