Probability of the limit equals the limit of the probability?
First, let me define the limit of a sequence of events, because I don't know how standard it is. Let $\Omega$ be a set and $\{ A_n \}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a sequence of sets s.t. $A_n\subseteq\Omega \ \forall n \in \Bbb N$. Then we define lim sup and lim inf like this:
$$lim \ sup(A_n) = \{\omega \in \Omega : \omega \in A_n \forall n\in L  \ \text{for some}\ L\subseteq \Bbb N  \ \text{with} \ |L|=|\Bbb N| \}$$
$$lim \ inf(A_n) = \{\omega \in \Omega : \omega \in A_n \forall n \geq k  \ \text{for some}\ k \in \Bbb N  \}$$
And the limit of the sequence exists when both of them are equal (and the limit is of course any of them).
Now, it is true that when we have a probabilistic space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ and a sequence of events $\{S_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subseteq \mathcal A$ which is monotone, then the limit of the probabilities is equal to the probability of the limit. But if it is not (necessarily) monotone and the limit of the sequence exists, then can we exchange probability with limit? I think that I can reduce this to the case when the sequence converges to $\emptyset$, but I can't prove that case; there is always a little detail that seems reasonable but not easy to prove. And a counterexample also seems not likely to me.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3366292/824640

Thanks, I understood

Yes. For any sequence of events $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ we have
$$ \cap_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m \subseteq A_n \subseteq \cup_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m \quad \forall n $$
Thus
$$P[\cap_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m]\leq P[A_n]\leq P[\cup_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m]\quad \forall n \quad (Eq. *)$$
Now we can define your liminf and limsup by:
$$ A_{inf}= \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\cap_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m$$
$$A_{sup}=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\cup_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m$$
and so by continuity of probability:
$$\left(\cap_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m\nearrow A_{inf}\right) \implies \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[\cap_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m]=P[A_{inf}]$$
$$\left( \cup_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m\searrow A_{sup} \right)\implies \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[\cup_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m]=P[A_{sup}]$$
If we are told that $A=A_{inf}=A_{sup}$ then we can take limits of (*) to get
$$P[A] \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[A_n]\leq P[A]$$
